# Help with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What am I doing wrong here??

```
  features = WidgetFeature.all(:conditions => {:widget_id=>params[:id], :children_features=>nil, :filterable => true" })
```

I want to find all those features where widget_id = params[:id] AND children_features IS NIL AND filterable IS TRUE

Comment: Did you mean to have double quotes at the end of your conditions hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
features = WidgetFeature.all(:conditions => {:widget_id=>params[:id], :children_features=>nil, :filterable => true })
```

This works. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
features = WidgetFeature.find(:all, :conditions => "[widget_id=? and children_features is NULL and filterable = true", params[:id] ]")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my perception the best way of doing this is

```
WidgetFeature.some_name_for_named_scope(params[:id])
```

IN WidgetFeature Model

```
named_scope :some_name_for_named_scope, lambda { |widget_id|
{ :conditions => ["widget_id = ? AND children_features = ? AND filterable = ?", widget_id, nil, true] }
}
```